# How to add specific styles to className in Tailwind

Tags: css, tailwind-css, classname

I am passing a style to a checkbox when it is checked, but I do it in my tailwind.css file.

I am wondering if it is possible somehow to do it in className inline, because I do not want really to add many global styles to tailwind.css.

So here's the component so whenever I check it adds an SVG instead of default checkbox:

```
            <input
                key={color}
                type="checkbox"
                className="peer hidden input:checked"
                name="checkbox-colors"
                checked={isChecked === color}
                value={color}
                onClick={(e) => {
                  handleColorChange(e.currentTarget.value);
                }}
                readOnly
              />
              <div className="h-full w-full flex justify-center items-center">
                <CheckIcon className="hidden" />
              </div>
```

and the styles are these:

```
input:checked + div svg {
  @apply block;
}
```

so if it is possible somehow to use it in input `className="peer hidden input:checked..."`

Comment: You can use `:checked` directly https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states

Answer (score 1):

Actually found a way around of using `cn` of `@classNames` and doing it like that:

```
<div className="h-full w-full flex justify-center items-center">
                <CheckIcon
                  className={cn({
                    hidden: isChecked !== color,
                  })}
                />
              </div>
```

and works like a charm!